# How to paste special in excel with python

Tags: python, excel, win32com

So I am trying to copy alot of data from one woorkbook to another.  The thing is that the data in the source workbook has some weird formating so I want to just get the values.  The code I have so far is this.

```
excel=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application");
excel.Visible = 1;
source = excel.Workbooks.Open(Cali.xlsm');
copy = excel.Workbooks.Open(temp.xlsx');
sdata = source.ActiveSheet;cdata = copy.ActiveSheet;
data=sdata.Range("89:89")
sdata.Range("89:89",data.End(4)).Copy()
```

now I can use

```
cdata.Paste()
```

but it pastes the formating as well

I found

```
cdata.PasteSpecial()
```

but it also pastes the formating.

Anyone who know how to use PasteSpecial() so it copies just the values or someone knows a better way I would be very apprecitave.

Comment: just an idea: isn't there a parameter you can pass in .PasteSpecial(), that will specify WHCIH Paste special to use ? In VBA, xlPasteValues has a value of -4163 .

Comment: That what im thinking but I'm still not sure how to pass it in and I had not known the value before.  If I just do cdata.PasteSpecial(-4163) I get an error

Comment: Does this help? http://www.mail-archive.com/python-win32@python.org/msg06368.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following which copies values from cells A1:A3 from one workbook to another.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
wkbk1 = "...\workbook1.xlsx"
wkbk2 = "...\workbook2.xlsx"
excel = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = 1
source = excel.Workbooks.Open(wkbk1)
excel.Range("A1:A3").Select()
excel.Selection.Copy()
copy = excel.Workbooks.Open(wkbk2)
excel.Range("A1:A3").Select()
excel.Selection.PasteSpecial(Paste=-4163)
```

wkbk1 and wkbk2 are file paths to two workbooks.

Comment: Alright with a little modification for the cells I wanted this worked.  Thanks